# Snowflake Snowsql - !source local file and output to csv

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Snowsql, Snowflake's CLI tool. I'd like to

- Load a local .sql file (with !source or !load) AND
- Save the output to a local csv.

If I've already connected to my Snowflake account and am running commands from the Snowsql interface, I have no trouble sourcing local queries (e.g. `!source query.sql`). However, I don't see how I can save the output to a CSV without hard-coding the output_file option. The results just print to the console.

If I'm not connect to Snowflake and I run a command from the terminal, I can run a local query and save to a CSV, but it appears to require authentication each time. For example, this works fine:

`snowsql -a account -u user --authenticator externalbrowser -f query.sql -o output_file=myresults.csv`

The issue is that I can only access Snowflake through SSO, and authenticating each time I run a query is inconvenient.

Comment: you can store the username and password in a SnowSQL config file,, you can try if it helps https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-start.html

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal, I can only connect to my account through SSO. I don't have a password.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn’t the !spool command do what you want? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#spool

Comment: Maybe, but it still requires two commands, then I have to turn it off later. And it looks like it only appends the output of every query to the chosen output file, rather than writing to separate files for each query.

Comment: I’m not clear why issuing a spool command before each query, if you want to output to a different file each time, is an issue. How are you expecting to write to a different file for each query without providing details of the output file each time - and, given that, why do you object to using the spool command to provide this information?

Comment: I was hoping to be able just to add a flag for the destination.